# Прошу помочь! Сохранить текст введенный пользователем WP

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

Очень прошу мне помочь.
Есть сайт на ворд прессе, с плагином регистрации пользователей Ultimate mamber.
Надо сделать так, чтобы когда он вводил в своем личном кабинете, информацию в поле Contact form 7, эти данные сохранялись для него навсегда. Не удалялись при перезагрузку страницы.

Т.е это должно выглядеть так:

Оставьте ссылку на фотографию для конкурса: "поле куда он ее вводит" кнопка "Участвовать"
Затем вместо всего этого появляется фраза "Спасибо за участие" и она больше никогда не исчезает. Т.е в лк пользователя остается навсегда именно эта фраза, а не появляется cf7 опять. Это вообще возможно реализовать? Подскажите код пожалуйста, и куда его вставлять)) Или мб это вообще не через контакт форм надо делать?

Очень очень прошу помощи

Comment: Зачем там CF7 когда у UM есть свои формы и можно их делать сколько угодно и вообще все что угодно. Создаем новую форму профиля и делаем с ней все что угодно. Главное пользовательский шаблон скопировать чтобы после обновления плагина ничего не слетело.

Answer (score 0):

Перед/после отправки письма cf7 сохраняй кастомный атрибут в usermeta

```
add_action( 'wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'save_user_custom_field' );

function save_user_custom_field() {
    $user_id = get_current_user_id();
    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'customkey', 1 );
}
```

В самом шаблоне уже выводи то что нужно

```
$customvar = get_current_user_id( get_current_user_id(), 'customkey', true );
if ( $customvar ) {
    //html
}
```